# .Net Static Variables and DLL Versions in the GAC

Tags: c#, dll

Have a question about static classes/variables and DLL versions.

If I have a static variable in a DLL (Version 1) and I load it into the GAC, then create a newer version of the DLL (Version 2) and load it into the GAC, when either version is called will it refer to the same variable in  memory?

**Example:**

- Client 1 sets a static variable `IsAuthenticated = True` in Version 1 of the DLL.
- Client 2 gets the value of the same static variable (`IsAuthenticated`) however its referencing Version 2 of the DLL.

The namespaces are the same.

Will/Should `IsAuthenticated` be True when Client 2 calls it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each (version of a) DLL has its own copy of all static variables even if both DLLs are loaded into the same process. Sharing memory *across* processes like that (that's my interpretation of the question) would be not only a technical nightmare but also a very bad idea.